# Checking if button is clicked with Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

How would I go about checking if a button was clicked using Ajax? I want to have a button that, when clicked, sends an Ajax request (already done), and be notified if the button was clicked.  I just don't know how to check if it was pressed from another source file, and what headers to send in the Ajax request.  My code is as follows (presuming that there is a button in my form named "button":

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function checkVote()
{
    request = new ajaxRequest();
    request.open("POST", "checkButton.php", true);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.send(params);
}

function ajaxRequest()
{
    try
    {
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch(e1)
    {
        try
        {
            request = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
        }
        catch(e2)
        {
            try
            {
                request = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
            }
            catch(e3)
            {
                request = false;
            }
        }                               
    }
    return request;
}
</script>
```

Comment: All I can say is... eww ActiveX... Please for all that is good, don't use it.

Comment: The boilerplate ajaxRequest isn't necessary here, I think.

Comment: How are you getting the button click event in the first place? That's what I'd like to see.

Comment: Using $_POST.  And @Kris, what would be the alternative to using ActiveX on an IE browser?

Answer (score 3):

All of the popular JavaScript libraries/frameworks send the `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` with a value of `XMLHttpRequest` to let your script know the request was made via Ajax. So if you  use jQuery, Prototype, etc, this will be handled for you (and make your JavaScript coding life easier). If not, you can set it yourself so you are following an accepted convention.

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] === 'XMLHttpRequest') {
  // Ajax request
}
```

Comment: And as a handy tip, make that a function. I called mine `using_ajax()`. That way I don't have hundreds of `if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']`s around my code everywhere, just `if(using_ajax())`es

Comment: But how would I get the equivalent of something like `if (isset($_POST['button']))` from another source file that I'm sending the Ajax request to?

Comment: The page that is receiving the Ajax request is where this code will go. Not the page that serves up the original content.

Comment: Exactly, that's the other source file.  For some reason, that source file isn't taking my $_POST request, so I was wondering what parameters to send with the Ajax request.

Comment: Your code looks right for sending POST data. There's no reason why it shouldn't be receiving it.

Comment: Never mind, I was able to receive it fine, my JavaScript was a little off.